# «Важно, не отложить на потом». Верна ли запятая после «важно»?

Tags: запятые

«Важно, не отложить на потом». Верна ли запятая после «важно»?

Comment: Предложение означает, что нельзя отложить на потом что-то важное? Или просто важно что-то не отложить на потом? См. "казнить, нельзя помиловать".

Comment: видимо, важно не отложить на потом...))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Важно(,) не отложить на потом.

Запятая не нужна, потому что это простое безличное предложение, а не сложное.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, для запятой нет никаких причин!

Comment: а вопрос «что?» можно задать....от слова важно...важно что? не отложить на потом...?

Comment: Не знаю, как строго считается, но я именно такой вопрос и задаю.

Comment: Это, наверное, сокращённый вариант предложения: "это важно, нельзя отложить на потом".

Comment: нет...это заголовок!